# Excel sheet to be mapped to XML Source schema file and then exported via VBA

Tags: xml, mapping

After tirelessly searching countless pages and sites I need some assistance with converting an excel file into a XML file.

The manual process is as follows:

- Excel sheet provided with data
- Developer Tab > Source > select schema
- Manually map each excel column to the source header
- Export

All that I have been able to achieve so far is how to add the XML Source into the excel file and save if the xml.Isexportable (however because the XML has failed it can not save)

Can anyone give me some guiders or starting points as to how I could potentially map the source header to each column?

Thanks